# How do i permanently save a value in an app(android studio)

Tags: java, android

I want to save an a value for example my full name(something that never changes and i will re-use it again all the time).I would like it to save it locally i guess.

```
 String str = "abc";
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This is my Toast message!" + str ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Sharedpreferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save small amount of data, like `key-value` pairs, eg. `Name=somename`, `uimode=dark` etc., then you can use Shared Preferences. If you want to save huge amount of data, then you must save it in database (SQLite or other one)